# Why can't I call a method from another class?

Tags: class, for-loop, object, methods

I have two classes, E and F.

In class F, I'm trying to call the method which I created in class E called printData(), but I'm unable to call it. There is an error which says 'printData cannot be resolved or is not a field'. What is the reason? See the screenshots below. I did import the package as well(import login.*;)

```
package login;


public class E {

    public void printData {
        System.out.println("Hello...");
    }
}
```

[Class E](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIAeO.png)

```
package testing;

import login.*;

public class F {

    public void main(String[] args) {

        B b = new B();
        b.printData
    }
}
```

[Class F](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1niYI.png)

Comment: Because printData is a method in class E not class B

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case it is not clear from my comment, your mistake is that in  your main method of class F, you are creating an object of class B, which clearly does not have a public method printData, as opposed to class E, which does.

As this is basically a typo, I am voting to close this question, as it is of very little use to other users. You should not be disheartened, if the question is closed. This is normal behaviour on this site, to try to restrict the size of the repository of questions and answers to ones, which would be of greater use to more people.

I have included your code within the body of the question (as you should have done). People here do not appreciate images, as they cannot be copied. This also makes it clearer than you have a syntax error in calling the method: you need `b.printData();`. Without the parentheses, the compiler takes printData to be a field, not a method, hence the nature of your error message.